# Blogger - comment in top of my header

Tags: css, blogger

I am working on a blog for a client.  The header at the very top has an HTML comment in it that I can't figure out how to get rid of.

Here is the URL:  http://www.erinkathleendunn.com/

Here is the source code around the area:

```
      <![CDATA[
      body {
        min-width: $(content.width);
      }

      .content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {
        min-width: $(content.width);
        max-width: $(content.width);
        _width: $(content.width);
      }

      .main-inner .columns {
        padding-left: $(main.column.left.width);
        padding-right: $(main.column.right.width);
      }

      .main-inner .fauxcolumn-center-outer {
        left: $(main.column.left.width);
        right: $(main.column.right.width);
        /* IE6 does not respect left and right together */
        _width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth -
            parseInt("$(main.column.left.width)") -
            parseInt("$(main.column.right.width)") + 'px');
      }

      .main-inner .fauxcolumn-left-outer {
        width: $(main.column.left.width);
      }

      .main-inner .fauxcolumn-right-outer {
        width: $(main.column.right.width);
      }

      .main-inner .column-left-outer {
        width: $(main.column.left.width);
        right: 100%;
        margin-left: -$(main.column.left.width);
      }

      .main-inner .column-right-outer {
        width: $(main.column.right.width);
        margin-right: -$(main.column.right.width);
      }

      #layout {
        min-width: 0;
      }

      #layout .content-outer {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 800px;
      }

      #layout .region-inner {
        min-width: 0;
        width: auto;
      }
      ]]>
    </b:template-skin>
  </head>

 <body expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'>
  <div class='body-fauxcolumns'>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer body-fauxcolumn-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can certainly help you..if you dont mind can you share complete code ? the above does not look like a complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I can see *-->* at the top of the blog. Is that what you want to remove ?

If yes, then Open your source code and search for `--&gt;` for in you HTML and remove that.

This will  work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in between the code of the "Mobile stylesheet". This is the portion of your code that is causing the problem:

```
.mobile .tabs-inner .PageList .widget-content .pagelist-arrow {
border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
</style>

--></style> (Remove this)

<style id='template-skin-1' type='text/css'><!--
```

This is on line 471 of the page. Also, you're closing the style tag 2 times here. The code is a bit messy. Try validating via http://validator.w3.org if you want to improve it overall.